# fgetcsv fails on a specific line

Tags: php, fgetcsv

My code works fine excepts for one line. It was working without any problem since one year but now there is one line in the file making my code buggy.

The line:

```
"26163796",,"85359","RDH001","30551","MDR001",349000,,"CAN",,,,"N","AI","N","O",,,,,2014/11/04,2015/06/30,"56083","C","Cousins Sud","304",,"Imp. Foucher",,"J3B8V3","4318433 Cadastre du Québec","O",2002,,,,,,,,,,,,"30 jours","30 days",,,,,,,"A.I.SEUL","R","PP","IS",,,,2001,,,49,35,,"P",,,,,,49.20,121.40,,"P",8858.70,"PC",,2014,80000,233200,12,4,2,2,2,0,"MT26163796.jpg","6292",,,,,,,,,,,,"Stores, rideaux, pôles, luminaires, lave-vaisselle, porte-poussière électrique, système de son au rez-de-chaussée, projecteur et colonne de son, véranda extérieur, chauffe-eau de piscine, paiement déjà fait pour ouverture de piscine au printemps, piscine récente..suite à l'addendum.","Blinds, curtains and rods, light fixtures, dishwasher, electric dust holder, sound system on main floor, projector and speakers, exterior veranda, water heater for pool, (payment has been done for opening of the pool next Spring.)see addendum...","Réservoir au propane loué $12/mois","Gas tank rented $12/month",,,,,,,,,"O",2015/01/06 01:17:29,,"EV",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"http://passerelle.centris.ca/redirect.aspx?CodeDest=REMAX%26NoMLS=MT26163796",,,"80508","RDD001",,,,,,,,45.29035900,-73.26586700,,,,,,
```

The code:

```
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== false) {

                $num = count($data);

                $row++;
                $values = '';

                for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    $values .= "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[$c]) . "', ";
                }
                if ($tableName == 'inscriptions') {
                    echo ($num) . "\n";
                }
                $values = substr($values, 0, -2);

                $query = "INSERT INTO `" . $tableName . "` ( $columns ) VALUES ( $values )";
                $this->_logFile[] = $query;

                mysql_query($query) or die('SQL ERROR:' . mysql_error() . ' : ' . $query);
                unset($values);
            }
```

In fact, the sentence : *"Stores, rideaux, pôles, luminaires, lave-vaisselle, porte-poussière électrique, système de son au rez-de-chaussée, projecteur et colonne de son, véranda extérieur, chauffe-eau de piscine, paiement déjà fait pour ouverture de piscine au printemps, piscine récente..suite à l'addendum."* is splitted on the comma and make my sql query invalid.

Any idea please?

Comment: charset issue causing one or more of the accented chars to be parsed as single-byte chars, one of which evals out to a `"`?

Comment: You mean the simple quote on " l'addendum " ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed:

```
public function utf8_fopen_read($fileName) {
        $fc = iconv('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8', file_get_contents($fileName));
        $handle = fopen("php://memory", "rw");
        fwrite($handle, $fc);
        fseek($handle, 0);

return $handle;
}

$fh = $this->utf8_fopen_read(self::UPLOADED_FILES_TXT . $fileName);

while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ',')) !== false) {
$data = array_map("utf8_decode", $data);
...
}
```